# H2 Database not working on Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, h2, h2db

I'm using **Maven** on **NetBeans** to import **H2 Database** to my project and the following code to init. a simple **embedded** database:

```
//...
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
//...
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/MCUsers");
//...
```

When I run the code on my Windows machine (where I do the programming), it works fine and I can create tables and rows. But when I run the same JAR file on my Linux machine, I get the following error:

> Error Code:90020 Message:Database may be already in use: **null**.
>   Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode
>   [90020-194] Cause:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked:
>   nio:/root/MCUsers.mv.db [1.4.194/7]

- The same JAR runs on my Windows machine with no problems.
- There are no other Java programs running on my Linux machine.
- I already tried to reboot the system - didn't work.
- Only The files MCUsers.mv.db & MCUsers.trace.db are created in the root directory after this error occurs.
- My Linux machine uses JRE1.8.0_112 to execute the JAR file.

**Edit:**
Adding "FILE_LOCK=NO;" also didn't work.

Comment: Coukd be file permission issue? Also, are you sure ~ is supported in the path? It's a shell thing, normally not expanded by many programs, (not sure of JDBC or H2).

Comment: Are you possibly opening the db more than once?

Comment: LevKuznetsov Yes, the only code in main is the one posted.
@hyde I'm running the JAR file with the root user, and the ~ is actually in the H2 getting started guides.

Comment: Running as root might also be the issue. There are programs which refuse to run as root due to security concerns. Probably not issue here, but not impossible.